# Using polar coordinate to sketch the graph of a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d

I want to sketch the following function, $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$, that is , $z=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$. By using polar coordinate, $  z=f(\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$. I think the next step I should rotate it around z-axis. Is that correct? If so, how I can do that? Is there another way to do the sketch without the polar coordinate?

Comment: What do you want to " rotate around z-axis" and why?

Comment: @AnneBauval, since the graph would be in 3d.

Comment: What is this "it" that you want to " rotate around z-axis"?

Comment: @AnneBauval, the curve of $\cos(2\theta)$

Comment: Is it that you give up sketching the graph of $f,$ and want to sketch the graph of $g(r,\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$ instead?

Comment: @AnneBauval, yes, do you know how to do the graph of $f$ by hand?

Comment: First, can you see why the graph of $g$ is not obtained by "rotating the curve of $\cos(2\theta)$ around the z-axis"? As for the graph of $f,$ first sketch it for $(x,y)$ on the unit circle and then use that $f$ is radially constant.

Comment: @AnneBauval, could you please tell me why?

Comment: @AnneBauval, If you could please put your last comment as an answer with details. This is great.

Comment: @AnneBauval, what did you mean by radially? and why did you want to do that graph?

Comment: Radially means along each line from the origin. And it is you who wanted to do the graph of $f.$

Comment: No. It was *me* :).

Comment: @AnneBauval, so, the graph would be in $\mathbb R^2$. right? For example, $f(1,0)=1$ so in this case, it would radially from the point $(1,0)$ up one. Is that right?

Comment: No, to $\Bbb R^2$ but $\Bbb R^3,$ as you said yourself in your 1st comment. I cannot say if " it would radially from the point (1,0) up one" is right or wrong (to me it means nothing). $f$ is radially constant and $f(1,0)=1$ so $f(t,0)=1.$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=3d+plot+z%3D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2-y%5E2%7D%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@00GB please get familiar with a tool that plots anything you want in 3d. The following is done with python:

[image]

Comment: Please get familiar with [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C130.3236).  This should have been, at most a comment.

Comment: @amWhy Agreed. To my knowledge comments do not admit to embed graphs. This entire thread should anyway be deleted.